# ¿Como desconectar de una sesión PHP en Javascript y redirigir a otra pagina?

Tags: php, javascript, session

Necesito que al pulsar en el botón de salir se desconecte de la sesión (se borre) y me redirija a la pagina de `login` y no se si lo estoy haciendo bien.

```js
 <script>
 document.getElementById('logoff').addEventListener('click', Salir);
 function Salir(){
  window.location.href = 'login.php';
  <?php
  unset($_SESSION['usuarios']);
  ?>
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo que crees una nueva página `logout.php` y que el usuario sea enviado cuando hace clic:

```
<!-- Código HTML -->
<script>
    document.getElementById('logoff').addEventListener('click', salir);
    function salir() {
        window.location.href = 'logout.php';
    }
</script>
<!-- Código HTML -->
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
```

De esta forma, cierras la sesión y lo envías a la página de `login.php`.

Comment: D10S muchas gracias! Justo lo que queria :D. En 7minutos la marco como respondida

Comment: Qué bueno que te sea de utilidad. Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta para cerrar el caso.

Comment: Rox tengo otra duda de php puedo preguntartela por privado? Es corta y me imposibilita continuar la tarea

Comment: Si es sumamente corta, haz tu pregunta por aquí. De lo contrario publica una nueva pregunta y con gustó te ayudaré si la respuesta esta a mi alcance

Comment: Lo malo es q son muchos ficheros y para montarlo en pregunta tela

Comment: Considera resumir tu pregunta y el código de la misma, y crear una nueva publicación. Quizá otro usuario de la comunidad puede responderte si no está a mi alcance. Además, esa respuesta será pública y le será de ayuda a otra persona con el mismo problema/duda.

Answer (score 0):

Digamos a manera de ejemplo que tienes el siguiente botón:

```
<a href="../driver/cerrar_sesion" class="nav-link">
   <i class="nav-icon fa fa-sign-out"></i>
     <p>Cerrar Sesión</p>
</a>
```

Es decir, para cerrar sesión tenemos que acceder al archivo "cerrar_session.php" en la ruta "../driver/cerrar_session", y ese archivo tiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 session_destroy();

 echo '<script language="javascript">
    alert("..:: SESIÓN CERRADA CORRECTAMENTE ::..");
    window.location.href = "../index";
    </script>';
?>
```

De esa forma te envía a la página index, si en esa pagina quiere controlar la sesión, simplemente agrega lo siguiente:

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'admin' ] ) || isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
} else {
    header( "Location: ../index" );
}
```